# Display slideshow of Private Photosets from Flickr

Tags: asp.net, html, embed, flickr

I have a number of photo sets that are marked as private on Flickr. I have a website and I would like to display all of them as Flash Sideshow.

I am currently using Flickr.NET open source library and I have created a web application to retrieve the list of all the photo sets. I can use other methods to display photos but I really like the embed slideshow feature of Flickr.

Hence my question - How should I code the Embed to display private photosets without making my photos as public ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it using the standard Flickr embed: http://www.flickr.com/help/blogging/#2937

All the embed parameters outlined here: http://paulstamatiou.com/2005/11/19/how-to-quickie-embedded-flickr-slideshows

I think the only way you can do this is to build it yourself using the Flickr.Net library. You'll need to authenticate with the Flickr API to access your private photos.

I assume from your question that the slideshow containign private photos must be going on a secured private website, otherwise you would just make the photos public?

Comment: The reason I want to have a slideshow is so that users can only view the photos and not download.
So, I want to have all private photos on Flickr and display SlideShow (Flickr one is good) on my blog.

I have got the same response from Flickr Support as well.

Comment: I think that the answer to the question is simply that it can't be done using Flickr's own slide show widget.